# return file data with GetChanges

Tags: development, web-services, csom

I am using CSOM to call the `GetChanges(changeQuery)` method so I can retrieve a list of changed files in my SharePoint site.

This is working great and I am seeing a collectionof `ChangeItems` as expected.

However, I am struggling to do the next part of my task, which is to retrieve the actual file data for each of the items in the collection of `ChangeItems`.

I can't find anything in the documentation that would indicate how to do this next part. So, given I have a collection of ChangeItems, how would I query each of the items and retrieve their properties?

If possible, I would like to get the following properties: `FileName, LinkingUrl, Author, TimeLastModified`.

Any help of guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the changes are retrieved via [`GetChanges` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.site.getchanges.aspx), the first step would be to determine changes that corresponds to a `File` object type:

```
var changes = ctx.Site.GetChanges(new ChangeQuery(true, true)); //all changes
ctx.Load(changes);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();


foreach (var change in changes)
{
      var changeFile = change as ChangeFile;
      if (changeFile != null)
      {
          //process ChangeFile       
      }
}
```

The next step would be identify the changed file via [`ChangeFile class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.changefile.aspx). It  exposes among the others the following properties:

- [`UniqueId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.changefile.uniqueid.aspx) - Gets a value that identifies the file that changed.
- [`WebId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.changefile.webid.aspx) - Gets a value that identifies the site that contains the changed file.

Using those properties the changed file could be identified within site collection as shown below

```
var web = allWebs.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Id == changeFile.WebId);
if (web != null)
{
    var file = web.GetFileById(changeFile.UniqueId);
    ctx.Load(file, f => f.Author, f => f.LinkingUrl, f => f.Name);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

where `allWebs` contains *all* the sites within a site collection. For that purpose I utilize [`RetrieveAllWebs` extension method](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/fb9442085eabc18c8810e55a150731a2):

**Example**

```
var changes = ctx.Site.GetChanges(new ChangeQuery(true, true)); //lets retieve all the changes for demonstration purpose
ctx.Load(changes);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

var allWebs = ctx.Site.RetrieveAllWebs(w => w.Url, w => w.Id);
var changedFiles = new List<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File>();
foreach (var change in changes)
{
     var changeFile = change as ChangeFile;
     if (changeFile != null)
     {
        if (change.ChangeType == ChangeType.Add || change.ChangeType == ChangeType.Update)
        {
           var web = allWebs.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Id == changeFile.WebId);
           if (web != null)
           {
                var file = web.GetFileById(changeFile.UniqueId);
                ctx.Load(file, f => f.Author, f => f.LinkingUrl, f => f.Name);
                changedFiles.Add(file);
           }
        }  
    }
}
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

//print results
foreach (var file in changedFiles)
{
      Console.WriteLine("LinkingUrl: {0}  Author: {1}  Name: {2}", file.LinkingUrl,file.Author.LoginName,file.Name);
}
```